# Detecting wordpress color picker button click

Tags: wordpress, color-picker

I'm coding a plugin and using the [wordpress color picker](http://make.wordpress.org/core/2012/11/30/new-color-picker-in-wp-3-5/) on a form but now I want to detect if the button is clicked and the wp-picker-holder shown up.

This is my jquery trying to listen to the click:

```
    $modal_edit.on( 'click', "a.wp-picker-container", function(){
        resize_modal_parent( $modal_edit );
    });
```

Unfortunately I can't achieve the result by guess there is an event which prevents re-eventing the click to a.wp-color-result

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Ok what I did was this:

```
$modal_edit.find('.wp-color-picker').wpColorPicker({ 
    change: function(event, ui){ resize_modal_parent( $modal_edit ); } 
});
```

Unfortunately I must wait the change of color to trigger the parent resizement.

Answer (score 0):

Three years old, I know. But I needed to achieve the same thing and limited info to search for.

In my case, I needed to trigger some CSS changes. I got it to work this way. Waiting for it to set up all color picker instances first.

```
setTimeout(function(){
    $modal_edit.find('.wp-color-picker').wpColorPicker({ 
        change: function(event, ui){ resize_modal_parent( $modal_edit ); } 
    });
},1000);
```

My usage for my code:

```
setTimeout(function(){
    $('body').find('.wp-color-picker').wpColorPicker({ 
        change: function(){
            CUSTOM_CAPTIONS_TEMPLATE_FOOGALLERY_EXTENSION.setPreviewClasses();
        } 
    });
},1000);
```